# How do I output all strings within a regex match in Powershell?

Tags: powershell

I want to search in a file for this regex:

```
<html:productType>.+?</html:productType>
```

How can I output in another file, all the matches of the .+? of the above regex?
Also, do you recommend any other tools/scripting languages for that kind of stuff?

Comment: What have you tried in Powershell to get the matches? You just show a regex expression.

Answer (score 0):

Since there is no information about data structure, is it XML or HTML or something else, Powershell and Regex would be good enough. I recommend regex named group to mark important fragment. See following demo:

```
#prepare demo data
@'
<node>
  <html:productType>ABC</html:productType>
  <html:productType>DEF</html:productType>
</node>
'@ | Out-File Demo.txt

cat Demo.txt | Select-String '<html:productType>(?<MyGroup>.+?)<\/html:productType>' | % {
    $_.Matches[0].Groups['MyGroup'].Value
} | Out-File Demo.out
```

Comment: thanks but is there a way not to use MyGroup? I want to just specify the regex and reference the part of the regex I need to return, then return all the parts from the regex matches to a file

Comment: Named group is the best way to reference interesting fragment in Regex - it tells what is marked using word(s). To select whole match, use `$_.Matches[0].Value`. Please describe more clearly what do you need in question - chances somebody answer will grow.